# i have an issue in understanding the DOM

Tags: javascript

I want to understand the basic difference between the following statements. Id is targeting a checkbox tag.

```
1] Var loc = document.getElementById("location");
   Console.log(loc);

2] console.log(document.getElementById("location"));
```

Ist one writes [object HTMLInputElement]
2nd writes the html code for the checkbox tag

Comment: *"Ist one writes [object HTMLInputElement] 2nd writes the html code for the checkbox tag"* Ummmm...what browser? Was everything else the same when you did the two tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). You declare a variable and saves the html  element as an object in loc, then you write to the console.

2). You write pure the html element object directly to the console.

There is no difference in the value that you write out to the console.

Comment: But it works for the button as var b = document.getelementbyid(btn); b.onclick and document.getelebyid(btn) both work same or even if it is sme output in console

Answer (score 2):

Your statements are identical in any real sense (other than the variable), it's just how `console` has displayed the result.

The console behaves differently (at least in Chrome) depending on whether it's open when you log something. My guess is that you had it closed for your first example but open for your second (or similar).

But it's about the console, not the DOM. In both cases, what you were passing to `console.log` was a reference to an HTML element.

Comment: It works if i write document.getelementbyid(loc).onclick and wont work if i save the retreive id in a variable like loc.onclick

Comment: @KamalAhmad: The code in that comment didn't make any sense, because you seem to be using `loc` in two different ways without saying what it is. If you have code that doesn't work, you can post a question about that code. *This* question wasn't about an `onclick` handler. But fundamentally, `document.getElementById("foo").onclick = ...` will be exactly the same as `var loc = document.getElementById("foo"); loc.onclick = ...` other than, of course, that you've declared a variable.

Comment: Im new here just signed up. Well the onclick handler works. As i said it doesnt work if i put it in var and display it in consoole or even with onclcik using that var as loc.onclick or console.log(loc)

Comment: I mean it work like display the object name bt it wont provide the same output as document.getelebyid(loc)

Answer (score 0):

Document.getelementbyid("loc").onclickworks but the this in a variable wont work and i think its not about browser and the var in console works if we save the textbox in a variable and push it to the console